# Android action bar above buttons

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-actionbar

This is my layout. Now I have my working toolbar, but the buttons are below the bar. I tried adding some margins here and there, but for some reason, one button is always not aligned with the others, even if I always used the same MarginTop. How can I fix this problem?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Start"
       android:id="@+id/button"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonP"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
       app:layout_marginTopPercent="2%"/>

<Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="&lt;&lt;"
       android:id="@+id/buttonP"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       app:layout_widthPercent="30%"
   app:layout_marginTopPercent="2%"/>

    <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="&gt;&gt;"
       android:id="@+id/buttonN"
       android:layout_above="@+id/custom_list"
       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/custom_list"
       app:layout_widthPercent="30%"
       app:layout_marginTopPercent="2%"/>

    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/custom_list"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:dividerHeight="1dp"
       android:layout_weight="0.5"
       android:layout_below="@+id/button" />
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Toolbar you should use Linear Layout and then your buttons.
You also need layour_weight property to align each button properly.
An example :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.App.PopupOverlay" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.3"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/menu_ic"
                    android:padding="5dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/xyz"
                android:textColor="@color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/grey" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_search"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="6.4"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:hint="@string/search_keyword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/darker_gray"
                android:textColorHint="@color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="@color/grey" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.3">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/notifications"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/notification_icon" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add Action bar Buttons**

Add an `<item>` element for each item you want to include in the action bar, as shown in this code example of a menu XML file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- "Mark Favorite", should appear as action button if possible -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_48dp"
        android:title="@string/action_favorite"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

The app:showAsAction attribute specifies whether the action should be shown as a button on the app bar. If you set app:showAsAction="ifRoom" (as in the example code's favorite action), the action is displayed as a button if there is room in the app bar for it; if there is not enough room, excess actions are sent to the overflow menu. If you set app:showAsAction="never" (as in the example code's settings action), the action is always listed in the overflow menu, not displayed in the app bar.

[Sample link](https://www.sitepoint.com/better-user-interfaces-android-action-bar/)

Comment: I have this code in another xml file and infact my Action Bar works. My problem is probably in the layout.